# Diameter of a Convex polygon using Rotating Calipers

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I am trying to solve the problem of finding the diameter of a convex polygon i.e a pair of points that have maximum distance between them.

> http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/diam.html

I have tried to implement the algorithm/pseudo-code mentioned here. But I am getting wrong answer for the polygon made using these points (-3,-4) (2,-3) (4,3) (0,5)

Clearly the diameter of polygon is (-3,-4) (4,3). But according to the pseudo-code mentioned here I get diameter as (-3,-4) (0,5)

```
struct vert
{
    long long int x,y,idx;
    double rad;
    int next;
    vert()
    {}
    vert(long long int _x,long long int _y)
    {
        x=_x;
        y=_y;
        rad=atan2(double(y),double(x));
    }
};
long long int dist(vert a,vert b)
{
    vert ab=b-a;
    return (ab.x*ab.x+ab.y*ab.y);
}
int cross(vert a,vert b,vert c)
{
    vert ab,ac;
    ab=b-a;
    ac=c-a;
    return ab.x*ac.y-ab.y*ac.x;
}
double area(vert a,vert b,vert c)
{
    double x=cross(a,b,c);
    x=abs(x/2.00);
    return x;
}
struct ret
{
    vert a,b;
    double dist;
};
ret comp(ret ans,vert a,vert b)
{
    if(dist(a,b)>ans.dist)
    {
        ans.a=a;
        ans.b=b;
        ans.dist=dist(a,b);
    }
    return ans;
}

ret rc_diameter(vector<vert> &v)
{
    int i,j,k,l,n;
    n=v.size();
    int a,b;
    int p,q,p0,q0;
    p0=p=0;
    q=1;
    ret ans;
    ans.dist=0;
    while(area(v[p],v[v[p].next],v[v[q].next])>area(v[p],v[v[p].next],v[q]))
    {
        q=v[q].next;
    }
    q0=q;
    ans=comp(ans,v[p],v[q]);
    while(q!=p0)
    {
        p=v[p].next;
        ans=comp(ans,v[p],v[q]);
        while(area(v[p],v[v[p].next],v[v[q].next])>area(v[p],v[v[p].next],v[q]))
        {
            q=v[q].next;
            if(p!=q0&&q!=p0)
                ans=comp(ans,v[p],v[q]);
            else
                return ans;
        }
        if(area(v[p],v[v[p].next],v[v[q].next])==area(v[p],v[v[p].next],v[q]))
        {
            if(p!=q0&&q!=p0)
                ans=comp(ans,v[p],v[v[q].next]);
            else
                ans=comp(ans,v[v[p].next],v[q]);
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

So can any when tell me if there is a problem in the pseudo-code or in my implementation
also when I applied this algorithm on the given set of points manually I am still getting (-3,-4) (0,5) as diameter.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late, but I saw that your initial value for p0 is incorrect. The p0 should be the last point in the list (pn) instead of the first point in the list (0). In other words, p0 is the previous point of the first point in polygon P, p is the first point in Polygon P, and q is the next point after p.